# How I can get the current year with the Js module of bucklescript?

Tags: reason, reason-react

I'm working on a ReasonReact project and I need to get the current year with the Js.Date module

I created a function to get a range between two years, so I need to pass the current year as the second parameter

```
let rangeYears = (startedYear, currentYear) =>
  Belt_Array.range(startedYear, currentYear) ->
  Array.to_list
  |> List.map(
    year => FormFieldSelect.{label: Js.Int.toString(year), value: `Int(year)}
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [instantiate a new Date](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Date.html#VALmake) type and use [getFullYear](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Date.html#VALgetFullYear).

```ml
let date = Js.Date.make()
```

```ml
let year = date->Js.Date.getFullYear
```

or, one-liner

```ml
let year = Js.Date.(make()->getFullYear)
```